# MagicalRecord never gives success in completion block

Tags: core-data, objective-c-blocks, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

Magical Record 2.2:

```
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            NSArray *cats = [Categorization MR_importFromArray:response.result];
        }completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

           //Success is always NO?!
        }];
```

However it does save my records. But they only appear when I restart my app.

I have even tried a loop with MR_importFromObject. Still saves but still no Success is true.

Comment: Maybe you could check the error...

Comment: the error returned is nil.

Comment: @jimijon I've got the same problem. Did you ever find out why this is happening?

Comment: @kmcgrady: Have you figure it out? Facing the same issue.